# Intermediary Table Design

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having difficulties understanding how a intermediary tables work.

This is my intended design: I have a 'users' table. Each user has a course/s that he's taking, 'course_id'. The name of the course is in the 'courses' table, and the intermediary table is 'users_courses'.

```
users:  
user_id (pk)

users_courses:  
user_id (pk)  
course_id

courses:  
course_id (pk)  
course_name
```

Is this the right way to go? It doesn't make sense to me, because I can't enter multiple values for the same user in a case where he's taking more than one course since it's going to create duplicate keys.
How do I make it work?

Comment: Put `user_id` and `course_id` in a single unique key to allow only one combination of a user and course but allowing a user user being in many courses.

Comment: I'm confused, how would you create such table? Does it mean that there's no primary key for `users_courses`?

Comment: @juergend - why? was that edit bad?

Comment: @vidit: You changed the code.

Comment: ohk.. I was trying to make it look like a table. Anyway, thanks for rolling it back :)

Comment: @vidit edit to format is fine but you should not change what original text is for example you change `course_id` to `id` that is considered as a radical change and not accepted.

Comment: You are describing a many to many relationship.  Since you don't seem to comprehend that, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @DanBracuk: I know it's a many-to-many relationship, that's why I'm asking about the intermediary table.

Comment: [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Hands-/dp/0321884493/?s=books&ie=UTF8)

Comment: @Prix - I have myself marked many such edits as radical change. It was a mistake :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow only one combination of a user and course but allowing a user being in many courses you have to put `user_id` and `course_id` in a single unique key.

```
create table users_courses
(
  user_id int,
  course_id int,
  unique index u_idx (user_id, course_id)
)
```

Comment: But doesn't MySQL require a primary key for each table?

Comment: No, it does not. And you could define a primary key as combination of 2 columns. So instead of a unique key define a primary key with the same columns.

Comment: So why not just do that instead of creating a unique key?

Comment: It does not matter. Do as you like.

Comment: @Wizardo Simplicity, for example, you could have the primary key as reference for further use such as deleting that user course by the id instead of key combination.